# Holomorphic versus algebraic $\mathbb C^*$-actions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I believe that the following is true:

**Statement.** A holomorphic $\mathbb C^*$-action on a complex projective manifold is algebraic if and only if it has a fixed point.

Where can I find a proof of this statement? Is it really true that no one ever wrote down this statement in such a form?

Comment: The "only if" follows from the Borel fixed point theorem.  The "if" follows from the structure theorems for group schemes over a field, usually attributed to Chevalley.  The identity component of the automorphism group scheme of your manifold is an extension of an Abelian variety by a linear algebraic group.  You want to prove that the induced homomorphism from your $\mathbb{C}^\times$ to the Abelian variety is a constant homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for this comment Jason! I wonder if there is a pedestrian reference for "if" part (one that uses the  complex geometry language and doesn't use the word "scheme"). Also where can I find this result of Chevalley? (I haven't succeeded so far with google).

Comment: Here is a link to an article of Brian Conrad proving Chevalley's theorem in modern language: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/chev.pdf